# Kubernetes Service: IPVS load balancing algorithm

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

As discovered [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/09/ipvs-based-in-cluster-load-balancing-deep-dive/), there is a new kind of kube service that are IPVS and have many algorithms for load balancing.

The only problem is I didn't find where those algorithms are specified.

My understanding:

1. `rr`: **round-robin**
   *-> call backend pod one after another in a loop*
2. `lc`: **least connection**
   *-> group all pod with the lowest number of connection, and send message to it. Which kind of connection? only the ones from this service ?*
3. `dh`: **destination hashing**
   *-> ?something based on url?*
4. `sh:` **source hashing**
   *-> ?something based on url?*
5. `sed`: **shortest expected delay**
   *-> either the backend with less ping or some logic on the time a backend took to respond in the past*
6. `nq`: **never queue**
   *-> same as least connection? but refusing messages at some points ?*

---

If anyone has the documentation link (not provided in the [official page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and still saying IPVS is beta whereas it is stable sync 1.11) or the real algorithm behind all of them, please help.

I tried: Google search with the terms + lookup in the official documentation.

Comment: Let's be clear on one point: "beta" is the Kubernetes implementation, but what you're asking is not beta in IPVS. Kubernetes IPVS is based on LVS, which is a product from the '90s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are defined in the code
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/proxy/apis/config/types.go#L193

- `rr` **round robin** : distributes jobs equally amongst the available real servers
- `lc` **least connection** : assigns more jobs to real servers with fewer active jobs
- `sh` **source hashing** : assigns jobs to servers through looking up a statically assigned hash table by their source IP addresses
- `dh` **destination hashing** : assigns jobs to servers through looking up a statically assigned hash table by their destination IP addresses
- `sed` **shortest expected delay** : assigns an incoming job to the server with the shortest expected delay. The expected delay that the job will experience is (Ci + 1) / Ui if sent to the ith server, in which Ci is the number of jobs on the ith server and Ui is the fixed service rate (weight) of the ith server.
- `nq` **never queue** : assigns an incoming job to an idle server if there is, instead of waiting for a fast one; if all the servers are busy, it adopts the ShortestExpectedDelay policy to assign the job.

All those come from IPVS official documentation : http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/docs/scheduling.html

Regards